# web scraping from a continously updated website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping data from a website which was updated continously(**like c2c e-commerce website**). I use **pagination** to get data from different pages. But the datas is updated as the bot navigates to the pages. How can I scrape the data in all pages in the **current time**?

I think multiple driver tabs is not useful because it freezes the driver (**I consider 1000 tabs in the same time**) and affects website like ddos attack.

Comment: does it have to be in python? if not, then I'd recommend jsoup, it's a java html parser

Comment: @Marek thanks for answer. can jsoup ensure the all page data in current time?. What is difference between selenium/beatifulsoup and jsoup?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "in current time"...the difference is in performance as well as jsoup isn't working with browser, not checking the state of page or elements and etc -> you can find more info here - https://jsoup.org/

Comment: @Marek I mean for example, the data of all products of all pages at 15:03. in 10.02.2022. So jsoup is almost the same as beatifulsoup( in python). This doesn't help me